# C# 'Not all code paths return a value' in switch statement while using default

Tags: c#, class, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a program that gives the next date after whatever date the user inputs. The code below is my NextDate class. I'm getting an error saying not all code paths return a value for my GetnextDate method, even though I've added a default. I really don't know what's going on, any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

```
namespace NextDate
{
    class Date
    {
        // Variables
        private int date;
        private int month;
        private int year;

        // Methods
        public Date(int d, int m, int y)
        {
            this.date = d;
            this.month = m;
            this.year = y; 
        }

        // Display methods
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s;

            s = "The date is " + this.date.ToString()
                + "/" + this.month.ToString()
                + "/" + this.year.ToString();
            return s;
        }

        private int GetNextDate(int d, int m)
        {
            switch(m)
            {
                case 04:
                case 06:
                case 09:
                case 11:
                    this.date = 01;
                    break;

                default: 
                    this.date = 31;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should write explicitly write  return 01;   not this.date=01

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/crdPL.png

Comment: I'm trying to write a program that gives the next date after whatever date the user inputs. Here are some screenshots of the code. i want it to print the full date of 31/04/2002, but it only displays 31. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3to6U.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/trCJS.png

Comment: @gggg43553rob @gggg43553rob **Please don't edit the question and revert it back to the previous question, because  in the edit, you are asking totally new question.** But as a note, you can simply use `AddDay` method of a `DateTime` to find the next day. for examle `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()` returns tomorrow date. **Please ask a new question if you need more help about this**

Comment: do you have any idea how to change where it says 31, to the format 31/04/2002 http://i.stack.imgur.com/crdPL.png

Comment: You can use `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("30/04/2002", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddDays(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));`

Comment: @gggg43553rob when you are asking a new question please create a new question. The idea is that the post and its answers are useful for people googling later. Now they are not as all the answers below are answering a different question. I'm going to revert your edit. Please post a new question with your new problem and mark on the the below as "correct".

Answer (score 3):

None of the paths return a value. Your method should return an `int` or the return type should be of type `void`.

Comment: It's technically correct +1, I think the question still needed more detailed an answer like [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33945966/3110834) Hope you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

change

```
private int GetNextDate(int d, int m)
```

in

```
private void GetNextDate(int d, int m)
```

Comment: It's technically correct +1, I think the question still needed more detailed an answer like [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33945966/3110834) Hope you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

The error message is self-describing, you didn't **return** anything from method, while it is supposed to return an **int** as return value (`private int GetNextDate(...)`)

**Option 1**

When you only want to perform a task, like set a value of `this.date` in a method, you don't need a return value for that method, so you can simply change the method signature to :

```
private void GetNextDate(int d, int m)
```

**Option 2**

But based on the method name **Get**NextDate and to make a more reusable method, its better to change the method to be able to return an int from the method.

You can write something like this:

```
private int GetNextDate(int d, int m)
{
    int date = 31;   
    switch(m)
    {
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            date = 1;
            break;
    }
    return date;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
this.date= GetNextDate(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is not returning anything, but it has a return type of `int`.

Maybe you meant to return `01` or `31` instead of setting `this.date`?

```
return this.date;
```

Or, if you want to set it, but not return anything, change the return type from `int` to `void`.